# Wide format causing bar plot data in ggplot to be doubled

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

In the process of creating an overlay bar chart with data in wide format, I noticed that my values for the bar chart are being doubled.

A quick fix was to **simply divide the values by 2**.

But what exactly is going on under the hood that is causing this to happen?

```
    # Data

status <- c("Infected","Not Infected")
female <- c(0.3,0.7)
male <- c(0.8,0.2)

# Colors

dark <- '#008AFE' # blue
lightest <-'#CCE8FF'
light_accent <-'#FFCB93' #peachy
lightest_accent <- '#FFE5C9'



df <- data.frame("Covid" = status,"female_perc" = female, "male_perc" = male)


gender_claim <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(data = df, 
           mapping= aes(x = c("Male"), y = male_perc[2]/2), 
           fill = light_accent, width = .25) +
  geom_col(data = df, 
           mapping= aes(x = c("Male"), y = male_perc[1]/2), 
           fill = lightest, width = .15) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),
                     labels = function(y) paste0(round(y*100,0),"%"), 
                     seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) +
  geom_col(data = df, 
           mapping= aes(x = c("Female"), y = female_perc[2]/2), 
           fill = lightest_accent, width = .25) +
  geom_col(data = df, 
           mapping= aes(x = c("Female"), y = female_perc[1]/2), 
           fill = dark, width = .15) +
  coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the illuminating [answer from Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65296991/13210554), here's an example of how to pivot your data and plot it:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -Covid,
    values_to = "fraction",
    names_to = c("sex", "type"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = fraction, fill = Covid)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

Here `pivot_longer` takes the sex information embedded in the column names of your original `data.frame` and makes them available to `ggplot` as a variable so you can programmatically access them and make your plot respond to them.

### UPDATE:

A 'tidy' solution with more manual control over aesthetics of each bar to achieve desired appearance:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -Covid,
    values_to = "fraction",
    names_to = c("sex", "type"),
    names_sep = "_"
  ) %>%
  arrange(desc(Covid)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = sex, y = fraction, group = Covid)) +
  geom_col(position = "identity", aes(width = rep(c(0.25, 0.15), each = 2), fill = letters[1:4]), alpha = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(lightest_accent, light_accent, dark, lightest)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1), breaks = seq(0, 1, by = .25),
                     labels = function(y) paste0(round(y*100,0),"%"), 
                     seq(0, 1, by = .25),expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0))) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip()
```

Note here the `arrange` call plots the bar in the desired order so those last in the `data.frame` get plotted last and go on top. The `width` and `fill` have to be set manually to match the desired order.

Comment: The issue I am seeing, is I would lose the flexibility in adjusting each bar in the overlay bar chart.

Comment: @Bjc51192 - Just updated my answer with some tweaks to get it to look like your original. Of course, to get that level of manual control the code gets a bit unwieldy but I think it's still significantly more readable, maintainable and generalizable than the original.

Comment: I actually did it slightly differnt using filtering. But your answer helped out.

Answer (score 2):

`ggplot` uses your data frame. When you use `geom_col(data = df, ...)`, `geom_col` will try to draw a geom for each row of `df`. You set explicitly that `x = "Male"` and `y male_perc[2]/2`, and those single values will be recycled for every row of the data frame.

It's the same as this:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = 1))
```

I give `ggplot` a data frame with 4 rows. I tell it `y = 1`, so the `y` value `1` is recycled and applied to all 4 rows. Your `x = "Male"` and `y = male_perc[2]/2` will be recycled over all 2 rows of data.

By default, `geom_col` will stack overlapping values on top of each other. So this is how your data is doubled.

Better than dividing by 2, you could use `position = "identity"` so nothing stacks. Better than that, put your data in long format and use the aesthetic mappings.